# BASE_DIR outputs correct using print, but in a variable it just outputs C:

Tags: python, django

If im using print on `base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR` it outputs everything correctly. However when I use this variable to create a new variable using `os.path.join`, it just outputs `C:`

Print example:
`C:\Users\me\Google Drive\gitlab\rootfolder`

Example on code where it just outputs `C:` and the paths after which shows up correct.

`blendfile = os.path.join(base_dir, '/var/media', userpathname, newest).replace("\\", "/")`

Comes out as:
`C:/var/media/userpathname/newest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **`'/var/media'`** to **`var/media'`** in **`join`** function, that is remove the ***preceeding slash*** from the second parameter.
hence the code should be,

```
blendfile = os.path.join(base_dir, 'var/media', userpathname, newest).replace("\\", "/")
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
In [16]: import os                                                                                                                                    

In [17]: BASE = "Users\me\Google Drive\gitlab\rootfolder"                                                                                             

In [18]: append_path__1 = "/var/media" # with preceeding slash                                                                                                                

In [19]: append_path__2 = "var/media"  # without preceeding slash                                                                                                               

In [20]: os.path.join(BASE,append_path__1)                                                                                                            
Out[20]: '/var/media'

In [21]: os.path.join(BASE,append_path__2)                                                                                                            
Out[21]: 'Users\\me\\Google Drive\\gitlab\rootfolder/var/media'
```